# Hook after admin changes editable setting in Mezzanine admin app

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

Does anyone know of a way (that does not involve monkey patching) to hook into Mezzanine's admin app and run some code after an editable setting is changed by the admin user inside the admin app (i.e. POST to `/admin/conf/setting/`)?

In my case the editable setting is created with a project specific [`defaults.py`](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html), e.g.

```
from mezzanine.conf import register_setting

register_setting(
    name="ENABLE_SOME_FEATURE",
    description="Enable/Disable feature",
    editable=True,
    default=False)
```

I couldn't find anything obvious after reviewing the documentation or `mezzanine.conf.admin` and `mezzanine.conf`.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each editable setting is backed by a Setting model instance:

https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/conf/models.py

Considering that, you could add a pre_save or post_save signal for the Setting model:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/